# D3 code producing error "Could not load image “filename.html”

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am learning D3.js using VS code IDE by working on examples from the internet/books. I found the following example in a book that tries to plot the following data. However, when I try to run the HTML (shown below) I get this error

*Could not load image “test1.html”.
Error domain 1 code 76 on line 22 column 8 of file:///home/wasim/Desktop/html_css/App_Dev/data_wrangling/test1.html: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 0 and head*

data (content of examples-simple.tsv, used in js code below)

```
x   y
100 50
200 100
300 150
400 200
500 250
```

test1.html content is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="examples-demo1.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="makeDemo1()">
<svg id="demo1" width="600" height="300"
style="background: lightgrey" />
</body>
</html>
```

examples-demo1.js content is as follows

```
function makeDemo1() {
    d3.tsv("examples-simple.tsv")
        .then(function (data) {
            d3.select("svg")
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 5).attr("fill", "red")
                .attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return d["x"]
                })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    return d["y"]
                });
        });
}
```

The output according to the book should look like this
[image]

any idea, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your svg tag is not closed properly: `<svg></svg>`

With the attributes your code should look like this:

```
<svg id="demo1" width="600" height="300" style="background: lightgrey;"></svg>
```

Comment: if use your syntax then I cannot open html in browser but the svg opens in an image application.